# Is there a function in R to pull all available packages and functions

Tags: r

I have a question. I need to go through the available packages and functions in R. Is there a way to pull all information in one code. If possible can we also extract why those particular packages/function is used for?

Comment: you might be interested in the `sos` package, which provides a number of features, including searching for functions by usage keywords, etc.

Comment: Thanks. But How do i extract?

Comment: Do you need `available.packages()`?! Or you want to go through locally available packages and list functions? Try `installed.packages()` with some ls.str

Comment: Yes it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant all available packages in your environment, the function **library()** should do the trick.
Otherwise, just visit the site below. They both list the packages and a short description for each.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html